# Collect all Distinct values of all columns in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table of cars called `my-project1.my-dataset1.cars` in my BigQuery database:

| year | make | model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Ford | Mustang |
| 2020 | Chevy | Camero |
| 2020 | Chevy | Corvette |
| 2019 | Honda | Odyseey |

I would like to create a query that contains the following information:

| column_name | number_of_options | distinct_options |
| --- | --- | --- |
| year | 3 | `[2023, 2020, 2019]` |
| make | 3 | `[Ford, Chevy, Honda]` |
| model | 4 | `[Mustang, Camero, Corvette, Odyseey]` |

I have tried the following query, but it does not work correctly:

```
WITH
    all_data AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   `my-project1.my-dataset1.cars` 
    ),
    column_names AS (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM `my-project1`.`my-dataset1`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = 'cars' 
    ),
    distinct_values AS (
        SELECT
            column_name,
            ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(select distinct column_name from all_data)) AS number_of_options,
            ARRAY(select distinct column_name from all_data) AS distinct_options
        FROM column_names
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM distinct_values
```

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong? Keep in mind that this is a simple example of a query. My actual table has over a hundred columns and each column has many distinct values so I really need an automated way to do this instead of listing everything out manually.

Comment: You can't inject like that in SQL, you can't really get away without typing out all of the column names somehow.  I would have a query that selects COUNT (DISTINCT col) AS col which produces 1 row, then do the same with STRING_AGG that also produces 1 row,  union all them together, and then with that as a CTE you can next PIVOT the whole thing. But even then you'll have to 'declare' the columns and type them out.

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach  - should be good start for you

```
SELECT key AS column_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT val) AS number_of_options,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT val) AS distinct_options
FROM (
  SELECT TRIM(x[0], '"') AS key, TRIM(x[1], '"') AS val
  FROM your_table t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'), ',"')) kv,
  UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(kv, '":') AS x)])
)
GROUP BY key
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 2023 year, 'Ford' make, 'Mustang' model UNION ALL
  SELECT 2020, 'Chevy', 'Camero' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2020, 'Chevy', 'Corvette' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2019, 'Honda', 'Odyseey'   
)
```

output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that in general, since SQL is a declarative language, you won't find a way to dynamically that without having to type out the columns you want.

The only way to do this, is through 3rd party tools or other systems that can sit between you and the warehouse, and dynamically write the SQL for you.

Here's an example of how you can use jinja.

First, instead of writing the query, write the a jinja template that will accept arguments and build the query for you.

```
WITH CTE_count AS (
SELECT 'Count of Values' AS metric
{% for col in column_list -%}
, COUNT(DISTINCT {{ col }}) AS {{col}}
{% endfor -%}
FROM TABLENAME
),
CTE_list AS (
SELECT 'List of Values' AS metric
{% for col in column_list -%}
, STRING_AGG(', ', {{ col }}) AS {{col}}
{% endfor -%}
FROM TABLENAME
),
METRICS_HORIZONTAL AS (
SELECT * FROM CTE_count
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_list
)
SELECT * FROM METRICS_HORIZONTAL
```

This template takes a list of columns, and renders the SQL for you like this:

```
WITH CTE_count AS (
SELECT 'Count of Values' AS metric
, COUNT(DISTINCT col1) AS col1
, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) AS col2
, COUNT(DISTINCT col3) AS col3
FROM TABLENAME
),
CTE_list AS (
SELECT 'List of Values' AS metric
, STRING_AGG(', ', col1) AS col1
, STRING_AGG(', ', col2) AS col2
, STRING_AGG(', ', col3) AS col3
FROM TABLENAME
),
METRICS_HORIZONTAL AS (
SELECT * FROM CTE_count
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_list
)
SELECT * FROM METRICS_HORIZONTAL
```

If you use the [website](https://j2live.ttl255.com/) to render the jinja, then you still have to pass in the list of columns, which means you'd still have to type out 100 things.

The advantage of a 3rd party tool or building something more robust yourself, is that you could generate that list dynamically, by querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA like you already noticed.

But since I'm not going to walk you through all that, then you might just use Excel or something to build the list for you.

```
column_list: ['col1','col2','col3']
```

(bottom left on the [website](https://j2live.ttl255.com/))

I hope that helps get you started.

Before I learned Jinja, I would just use excel and do something like:

1. query 1 row of data
2. Paste special (transpose) into excel, so the headers go down vertically
3. Use excel formulas to assemble the syntax: `, COUNT(DISTINCT col ) AS col`
4. Drag formula
5. Copy/Paste into my SQL

Answer (score 0):

Well I think @Mikhail's answer is more clever and flexible, you can do this with BigQuery's new [procedural language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language)...you can concatenate formatted strings into an SQL query then execute it:

```
DECLARE y STRING DEFAULT ''; 
  
FOR c IN (
  SELECT CAST(column_name AS STRING) AS column_name
  FROM `XXXX`.`YYYY`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'ZZZZ'
) 
DO
        IF y = '' THEN
                SET y = FORMAT('select "%s" as column_name, count(distinct %s) as number_of_options, array_agg(distinct cast(%s as STRING)) as distinct_options FROM `XXXX.YYYY.ZZZZ`',c.column_name,c.column_name,c.column_name);
        ELSE
                SET y = FORMAT('%s union all select "%s" as column_name, count(distinct %s) as number_of_options, array_agg(distinct cast(%s as STRING)) as distinct_options FROM `XXXX.YYYY.ZZZZ`',y,c.column_name,c.column_name,c.column_name);
        END IF;
END FOR;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE y;
```